# Pandas - make new column with 2 classes where last row by id is another class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have Data Frame with IDs in the first column and number of cycle in second.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]]),
               columns=['ID', 'cycle'])

ID    cycle    
1     1         
1     2        
2     1       
2     2
2     3
```

I want to make new column with 2 classes: 'last cycle', 'not last cycle':

```
ID    cycle  group   
1     1        0 
1     2        1
2     1        0
2     2        0
2     3        1
```

How to solve this task?

Thanks in advance for replies

Answer (score 4):

Many ways to do this.

One is to use`groupby.tail(1).index`

```
df2.loc[df2.groupby('ID').cycle.tail(1).index, 'group'] = 1
df2.fillna(0)
```

---

```
ID    cycle  group   
1     1        0 
1     2        1
2     1        0
2     2        0
2     3        1
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us do `transform` with `last`

```
df2['group']=df2.cycle.eq(df2.groupby('ID').cycle.transform('last')).astype(int)
df2
Out[244]: 
   ID  cycle  group
0   1      1      0
1   1      2      1
2   2      1      0
3   2      2      0
4   2      3      1
```